# How to add onmouseleave property on the textbox in RazorViewEngine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I'm working in ASP.Net MVC5 where I want to match password field with **confirm password** by using Javascript but since it uses Razor View Engine I can not add **onmouseleave** property on my `textbox`.
Please help nad thanks in advance.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmedPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = " CPswd", @onmouseleave = "Show();" } })
```

and it is giving me this error-

> CreateUser:122 Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'value' of null  at Show (CreateUser:122) at
>   HTMLInputElement.onmouseleave (CreateUser:105)Show @ CreateUser:122
>   onmouseleave @ CreateUser:105

at Createuser122 is this code -

```
var pswd = document.getElementById('Pswd').value;
```

and at CreateUser105 is this code -

Comment: *since it uses Razor View Engine i can not add onmouseleave property on my textbox*.....why? what is the issue?

Comment: @Mamun sorry for half informed question , i've edited it please look once again

Comment: Not sure but you can try wrap your JS with `DOMContentLoaded` described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: @Mamun i'm pretty new to Javascript so this link and it's content is going way over my head, any simpler solution??

Comment: Didn't notice the mismatch in ID you have used in the code and in the element, please check Derrick's answer....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your ID defined as " CPswd" while you're trying to `getElementById()` of Pswd.  You're getting null while calling `getElementById()` since it doesn't exist (because of the text mismatch).  I would also remove the space.

Comment: no " Cpswd" and "Pswd" are two different textbox's id and  i just rechecked it.

Comment: Are you able to add more relevant code?  You've provided code from two different sections that aren't directly related.